# JSON array from Django to Android

Tags: java, android, django, json

I'm having trouble trying to parse a json array string sent from Django to an Android. This is the format of the json string.

```
[
    {
        "pk": 1,
        "model": "brete.brete",
        "fields": {
            "contenido": "93iw09if",
            "fecha": "2011-05-07 03:06:40",
            "codigo_confirmacion": "",
            "correo": "oij8@gmail.com",
            "activado": false,
            "titulo": "234"
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 2,
        "model": "brete.brete",
        "fields": {
            "contenido": "asoidjfdiso",
            "fecha": "2011-05-07 03:08:09",
            "codigo_confirmacion": "",
            "correo": "oijoiji@oijoi.com",
            "activado": false,
            "titulo": "ijj"
        }
    }
]
etc
```

This is how I'm grabbing the data:

```
        //parse json data
        try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Brete resultRow = new Brete();
                resultRow.contenido = json_data.getString("contenido");
                resultRow.fecha = json_data.getString("fecha");
                resultRow.correo = json_data.getString("correo");
                arrayOfWebData.add(resultRow);
            }
        }
        catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }
```

I'm trying to get the data of `'contenido'`, `'fecha'` and `'correo'` But I'm not getting any rows displayed. This is not the whole code and maybe the problem lies somewhere else, but I have a hunch this might be a problem of not parsing correctly the nested json with json_data.getString(). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you grab your fields you actually have to reach for the "fields" object:

```
//parse json data
try{
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
        JSONObject buf = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject json_data = buf.getJSONObject("fields");
        Brete resultRow = new Brete();
        resultRow.contenido = json_data.getString("contenido");
        resultRow.fecha = json_data.getString("fecha");
        resultRow.correo = json_data.getString("correo");
        arrayOfWebData.add(resultRow);
    }
}
catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
}
```